# how to display post category with image in grid layout in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display dynamic post categories with images in a grid layout in a custom template.
I am using Category Images plugin to assign an image to categories.

Comment: please post the code that you have tried

Comment: I have only used wp_list_categories() function. I am new to customization. @Exprator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
<?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat) : ?>
<li>
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

you can get the image like this and then put it in the html of your need, see i am not a html developer so have no idea, i gave you how you can get the image and name now put the structure as you need